# SwiftUI, Render text off screen that is inside an HStack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have three views inside an `HStack`. The first two are `HStack`'s and the third is text. I want to use `.offset` to make the `Text` go off screen. I then have a `DragGesture()` which allows me to pull the view over.

Although when I pull, the text is not there. I played around with the `.offset` value and when I lowered it so only part of the text is off screen, the rest of the text is not there.

How can I get the text to render/ actually be viewable once I drag the screen?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
               
                        HStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            
                            Spacer()
                        
                        Text("Hello, world! Testing, Testing")
                            .padding()
                            .lineLimit(1)
                    }
                    
                .padding()
                        .animation(.spring())
                        .offset(x: draggedOffset.width)
                        .gesture(DragGesture()
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        self.draggedOffset = value.translation
                                    }
                                    .onEnded { value in
                                        self.draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
                                    }
                        )

    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. The main thing here is [`.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize(horizontal:vertical:)) - that lets the `Text` expand horizontally. There's no need for `.lineLimit(1)`.

You should also remove the `Spacer()`s. Because those also expand horizontally, SwiftUI will get stuck trying to figure out which ones to expand and which to not.

Then, there's the `Color.clear`. This has a couple purposes:

- Give expected resizing behavior: `Color` can be freely resized, so if you ever want to use `ContentView` inside another `View`, you won't run into trouble.
- Align the `HStack`: Because it's wider than the screen width, SwiftUI will center it by default. You want it aligned left, so you can pass in `.leading` to the [`alignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/background(_:alignment:)) parameter.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear /// placeholder view that fills the screen width
            .background( /// use this to constrain everything to the bounds of the screen
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100) /// `alignment` is unnecessary here
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    
                    Text("Hello, world! Testing, Testing")
                        .padding()
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) /// make the Text extend as much as possible horizontally
                }, alignment: .leading /// align everything left
            )
            .padding()
            .animation(.spring())
            .offset(x: draggedOffset.width)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.draggedOffset = value.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        self.draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Tried to implement this into my actual code, I actually need the text to be hidden off screen until dragged to reveal. Is there a way to anchor to where the right box is at the right of the screen?

Comment: @Kyronsk8 in this case, you might need to use `GeometryReader` + `overlay`. Might be good to ask a separate question though.

Comment: I managed to get the result by just adding 100 to the ```.padding``` of the first square, however I can't replicate it in my main project code as it is much more complicated. I will keep trying before I post another question. Thank you.